Proof of theorem $V.4.1(c)$ in Silverman Elliptic Curves, How to Deduce $H_p(t)$ has no multiple roots?
I am trying to understand the proof of theorem $V.4.1(c)$ in Silverman Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves. Let $p$ be a prime, $q=p^n$, and $m=(p-1)/2$. Define the polynomial
$$H_p(t)=\sum_{i=0}^m \binom{m}{i}^2 t^i$$
Silverman claims that this polynomial has distinct roots, and the argument proceeds as follows.

Let $\mathcal D$ be the differential operator
$$\mathcal D=4t(1-t)\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+4(1-2t)\frac{d}{dt}-1.$$
Then by direct calculation and using the fact that $m=(p-1)/2$, we deduce
$$\mathcal{D}H_p(t)=p\sum_{i=0}^m (p-2+4i)\binom{m}{i}^2t^i.$$
In particular, since $\text{Char}(\mathbb{F}_q)=p$, we obtain
$$\mathcal D H_p(t)=0\qquad \text{in }\mathbb{F}_q[t].$$
Hence the only possible multiple roots of $H_p(t)$ are $t=0$ and $t=1$.

I don't follow how we obtain that the only possible multiple roots are $t=0$ and $t=1$. I believe  can get part of the way there, but not all the way. In particular, let $\tau\neq 0,1$ be a multiple root of $H_p(t)$. Then we have
$$H_p(t)=(t-\tau)^2h_p(t).$$
For some polynomial $h_p(t)$. Then
\begin{align}
0=\mathcal{D}H_p(t)&=4t(1-t)\left(2h_p(t)+2(t-\tau)h_p'(t)+h_p''(t)\right)\\
&+4(1-2t)\left(2(t-\tau)h_p(t)+(t-\tau)^2h_p'(t)\right)\\
&+(t-\tau)^2h_p(t)
\end{align}
Substituting $t=\tau$, we get $4\tau(1-\tau)h_p(\tau)=0$. Since $\tau\neq 0,1$, this implies $h_p(\tau)=0$. So this means that if $\tau$ is a multiple root, then it must be a triple root. However, I cannot figure out how to conclude from here.
Silverman's textbook cites Class number of a definite quaternion with prime discriminant by Isuga as the source for this proof. I indeed found the section of that paper which covers this argument, but it provided no more details than Silverman did.

Make the assumption that there is a zero of order $k>1$ at $t=\tau$ with $\tau\ne0,1$ - $H_p(t)=(t-\tau)^kf(t)$ with $f(\tau)\ne 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
H_p'(t) &= (kf(t)+(t-\tau)f'(t))(t-\tau)^{k-1}\\
H_p''(t) &= (k(k-1)f(t)+2k(t-\tau)f'(t)+(t-\tau)^2f''(t))(t-\tau)^{k-2}
\end{align*}
Then compute $DH_p(t)$. You can show that $DH_p(t)$ has a zero of order exactly $k-2\ge 0$. This follows from the fact that $DH_p(t)=4\tau(\tau-1)k(k-1)(t-\tau)^{k-2}+$ terms divisible by $(t-\tau)^{k-1}$, which you get by explicit calculation. This contradicts the fact that $DH_p(t)$ is the zero polynomial.

For a more insightful way to see what is going on: if a power series $f(t)\in k[[t]]$ satisfies a linear differential equation of order $n$, $Lf=0$ where
$L=\sum_{i=0}^na_i(t)\partial^i$
with $a_i(t)\in k[[t]]$, then this corresponds to a linear recurrence relation amongst its coefficients. It follows that if $n-1$ consecutive coefficients of $f(t)$ vanish then $f(t)=0$. In particular, a non-zero solution $f(t)$ to the DE can only have order at most $n-1$ (the order of $f$ is the smallest $k$ such that the $k$th coefficient of $f$ is not zero, or the largest $k$ such that $t^k|f$).
For the problem at hand, take $H_p(t)$ to be an element of $\mathbb{F}_q[[t-\tau]]$ for $\tau\ne 0,1$. The order of the differential equation is $2$, so the order of the zero is at most $1$.

I suppose there is probably something to be said about whether $p|4k(k-1)$, but this is satisfied here since the degree of the polynomial is less than $p$. Anyway, thank you for the insightful answer.
